# number bytes read from gpio input is zero

Tags: linux, io, gpio, sysfs

I have some strange behaviour when trying to read gpio output pin.
I get that the first read return 1 (1 bytes read), but all next read from same gpio return 0. I would assume that it should always read 1, because there is always something to read from input pin.

```
gpio = 8;
fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY);
sprintf(buf, "%d", gpio);
rc = write(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
if (rc == -1)
    printf("failed in write 17\n");
close(fd);
sprintf(buf, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/direction", gpio);
fd = open(buf, O_WRONLY);
rc = write(fd, "in", 2);
if (rc == -1)
    printf("failed in write 18\n");
close(fd);
sprintf(buf, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", gpio);
gpio_tdo = open(buf, O_RDWR);
rc = read(gpio_tdo, &value, 1);   <-- rc here is 1

rc = read(gpio_tdo, &value, 1);   <-- rc here is 0

rc = read(gpio_tdo, &value, 1);   <-- rc here is 0
```

Should the read of one byte from the gpio input always return 1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [man read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read):

> On files that support seeking, the read operation commences at the current file offset, and the file offset is incremented by the number of bytes read. If the current file **offset** is at or past the **end of file**, **no bytes are read**, and read() returns zero.

So probably you need to execute [lseek](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek) before second reading, like this:

```
read(gpio_tdo, &value, 1);
lseek(gpio_tdo, 0, SEEK_SET);
read(gpio_tdo, &value, 1);
```

The second choice you have is to close file and reopen it before doing second `read`:

```
close(gpio_tdo);
gpio_tdo = open(buf, O_RDWR);
read(gpio_tdo, &value, 1);
```

But it seems like a bit overhead. I'd go with first option  (`lseek`).

Useful reading: [gpio in sysfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt)